# AWS Lambda GO PathError (Windows 10)

Tags: go, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-go

I've done the following in PowerShell in VSCode:

```
PS D:\Project Resume> set GOOS=linux
PS D:\Project Resume> set GOARCH=amd64
PS D:\Project Resume> set CGO_ENABLED=0
PS D:\Project Resume> cd .\dist\events\
PS D:\Project Resume\dist\events> go build -o main main.go
PS D:\Project Resume\dist\events> ~\Go\Bin\build-lambda-zip.exe -o main.zip main
2020/11/14 14:05:13 wrote main.zip
```

This seems to zip the file fine, and I changed the handler to "main" in the Lambda console as well. However, I'm still getting this:

```
START RequestId: 42d5f7d6-3c9d-457d-ab2f-5030b39a5bce Version: $LATEST
fork/exec /var/task/main: exec format error: PathError
null
END RequestId: 42d5f7d6-3c9d-457d-ab2f-5030b39a5bce
REPORT RequestId: 42d5f7d6-3c9d-457d-ab2f-5030b39a5bce  Duration: 0.43 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 24 MB  Init Duration: 2.84 ms
```

If this matters, here's the code I have (I followed a tutorial on YouTube, using "main.go" as file name):

```
//Lambda Function Go Code
package main

import (
    "errors"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

func main() {
    lambda.Start(HandleRequest)
}

//HandleRequest the request handler for our lambda stuff
func HandleRequest(request events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    if request.HTTPMethod == "POST" {
        var stringResponse string = "Success :)"
        APIResponse := events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{Body: stringResponse, StatusCode: 200}
        return APIResponse, nil
    }
    err := errors.New("Method Not Allowed")
    APIResponse := events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{Body: "Method Not OK", StatusCode: 502}
    return APIResponse, err

}
```

Out of curiosity, I decided to check the permissions of the zip file as well. Could this have something to do with it, possibly???

[image: main.zip permissions Windows 10]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, I was following documentation, thinking the COMMAND to set the GOOS env variable was something like this:

```
set GOOS=linux
```

However, according to the following documentation:

https://mcpmag.com/articles/2019/03/28/environment-variables-in-powershell.aspx?m=1

Since I was running in PowerShell, I SHOULD'VE used THIS command:

```
$env:GOOS = "linux"
```

As many docs will say elsewhere, you'll know you've set the env variable correctly when you use the following in PowerShell, whether from VSCode or outside of that IDE:

```
go env
```

I hope this helps someone out compiling in Windows down the road.

Comment: Wow! I'm working also on Windows 10 and I could see that my GOOS env variable was not changing until I ran $env:GOOS = "linux" command and then do again a go build -o main Then I zipped the file and I've uploaded again to Lamda and now works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

as per [documetation](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/lambda/latest/dg/golang-package.html)
**The handler parameter must match the name of the executable containing your handler.**

have you updated the handler name in the lambda configuration  to `main`

by default its set to `hello`
[image]

Update it to `main`

Comment: Hi there - thanks for the answer, but yes, I did just that.

Comment: @sorry missed that part . i did that mistake as a rookie . but double check env variable for GOOS Is set before running the build

Comment: I think I did set the env variable, but best way to check? Not that I'm not willing to dig but will take anything before I get back in front of my laptop